# FileApi (Chrome) callback method is not called when alert box is added

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, callback, dom-events, fileapi

I have simple to explain problem but I was not yet able to find an answer to that question.

In the following code everything works fine. Means the callback method which logs some text to the console is called and the file system is ready.

**But:** As soon as I add an alert()-Box right after the `requestQuota()` method call, my callback method is never called (neither the handleError callback method).

(This only appears in Google Chrome as it is the only browser supporting FileApi.)

For me it seems like Google Chrome looses the handle to that callback method if you add a blocking alert-statement right afterwords. But that really shouldn't!?! Or is there another reason why?

```
    // Note: The file system has been prefixed as of Google Chrome 12:
    window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

    //ask for permission
    window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(PERSISTENT, SIZEINBYTES, function(grantedBytes) {
          window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, function(fileSystem){
              console.log("Callback method: The file system for chrome is ready.");
          }, handleError);
    }, handleError);
    //Add: alert("requested."); --> Callback method isn't called...
```